# How to fire event if model property changes

Tags: c#, .net

I developing  application using backround processes and MVP pattern. 
Can I store states of processes (isCanceled, isStarted or isPaused) in ModelProcess (Model) like this:

```
public event EventHandler CancelChanged;
  bool isCanceled = false;
    public bool IsCanceled
    {
        get { return isCanceled; }
        set
        {
            isCanceled = value;
            if (isCanceled)
            {
                if (CancelChanged != null)
                {
                    CancelChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should take if (isCanceled) off. Otherwise you will be notified only when isCanceled is set to true. You might have cases where you might be switching between state back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setter will only call `CancelChanged` if `isCanceled` is being set to `true`, no matter if it has been `false` before. The following code will check if there is an actual change of the value, wich makes it idempotent.

```
set
{
    if (value != isCanceled)
    {
        isCanceled = value;
        if (CancelChanged != null)
        {
            CancelChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it makes no difference in my case. I asked only about MVP pattern. Can the states of processes store in Model Layer?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you shouldn't be able to. You can store anything you like in your model classes.

Comment: Seems to me you're risking a code readability issue when choosing the name CancelChanged for that event, as it hints it reflects any change to the Canceled property and not just the change from true to false. Isn't there a better name for it, such as CancellationReversed? Just my 2c